# Grouping An array of Objects By A field

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var array1= [
    { name : "1", desc: "in odd", cat:"1" },
    { name : "3", desc: "in odd" ,cat:"2" }
];

var array2= [
    { name : "1", desc: "in even", cat:"1"},
    { name : "2", desc: "in even", cat:"1" },
    { name : "4", desc: "in even", cat:"1" }
];
```

I wanted to merge the arrays and consolidate into an array so that it should group any cat(final output should be an array of objects)

After merging i wanted to sort the consolidated list by name.Can we have  some  ways to optimized ways to achieve the same?

Comment: How the final array should look like?

Comment: `[array1, array2].flat()` to . merge the arrays and after this you want to do group by ?

Comment: Please add the expected output. There are plenty of duplicates for this

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```js
var array1 = [
  { name: "1", desc: "in odd", cat: "1" },
  { name: "3", desc: "in odd", cat: "2" }
];

var array2 = [
  { name: "1", desc: "in even", cat: "1" },
  { name: "2", desc: "in even", cat: "1" },
  { name: "4", desc: "in even", cat: "1" },
];
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);

var objConsolidated = {};

array3.forEach(element => {
  if(objConsolidated[element.cat]){
    objConsolidated[element.cat].push(element);
  } else {
    objConsolidated[element.cat] = [];
    objConsolidated[element.cat].push(element);
  }
});

console.log(objConsolidated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Mean

```
var array1= [
    { name : "1", desc: "in odd", cat:"1" },
    { name : "3", desc: "in odd" ,cat:"2" }
];

var array2= [
    { name : "1", desc: "in even", cat:"1"},
    { name : "2", desc: "in even", cat:"1" },
    { name : "4", desc: "in even", cat:"1" }
];



function getCatItems(cat){
    var n = [array1, array2].flat();
    return n.filter(i=>(i.cat==cat));
}
 console.log(getCatItems("1"));
```